# Simpliest way to add text using excelwriter

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below code to write a dataframe to an excel file. I would like to add a sentence below the table 'Data extracted on 2016-12-22'. What is the simpliest way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1')

print('Data extracted on ',pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['1']

text = 'Data extracted on ' + pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
worksheet.write(len(df) + 1, 0, text)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

See also: [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)